# Trim csv file using command line

Tags: mysql, csv, command-line, trim

I have very large .csv files containing raw data.  Many fields have leading and trailing spaces, and many multi-word field values that are supposed to have only one space in between character-groups/words have extra spaces, e.g.

```
'12   Anywhere  Street'
```

which should be:

```
'12 Anywhere Street'
```

The leading, trailing and extra spaces vary from one extra space to six extra spaces.  I can load the files into my DB and run scripts to trim them.  The leading and trailing trim scripts work well and are executed quickly; however, the scripts to remove the extra spaces in between words are much longer and time-consuming.  It would be better to remove the extra spaces in between words in the raw .csv file using the command line before loading it into my DB.

I basically need to run a replace function that replaces any instance of "  " to " ", "   ", " ",.... up to six spaces or so.  I would greatly appreciate some assistance with achieving this.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Linux?  Please mention it in your question.  Also can you give an example of a few rows of your data file?

Comment: Using windows but can easily create a Linux instance to do this in.  The columns that have extra spaces between words contain (quoted by field) 'first and last name', 'street address', 'city', 'string of text in sentence format'.    Certain tables/.csv files have many more extra spaces than others.  I hope that helps.

Comment: The message box is automatically removing the spaces.

Comment: Well if it's easy for you, I'd recommend creating a linux virtual (or even a dedicated real machine if you have a large volume of data).  Then there are several tools that lend themselves to this kind of task.  Processing your files with perl, sed or awk will allow you to process text in this manner.  If you are simply interested in removing spaces then I think awk might be the best performing tool while having a great deal of flexibility and conciseness.

Comment: These all use regular expressions (regex) to do pattern matching and substitution, but performance can vary, it's best to experiment which the most efficient tool.  I have used awk a few times and I find it very powerful without having to write huge scripts.  Awk is ideal for field-based data.

Answer (score 2):

In Part 1 of this response, I'll first assume that your CSV file has a field separator (say ",") that does NOT occur within any field.  In Part 2, I'll deal with the more general case.

**Part 1.**

```
awk -F, '
  function trim(s) {
    sub(/^  */,"",s); sub(/  *$/,"",s); gsub(/   */," ",s); return s;
  }
  BEGIN {OFS=FS}
  {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { $i=trim($i) }; print }'
```

**Part 2.**

To handle the general case, it's best to use a CSV-aware tool (such as Excel or one of the csv2tsv command-line tools) to convert
the CSV to a simple format wherein the value-separator does not literally occur within the values.
The TSV format (with tab-separated values) is particularly appropriate since it allows a representation of tabs to be included within fields.

Then run the above awk command using `awk -F"\t"` instead of `awk -F,`.

To recover the original format, use a tool such as Excel, tsv2csv, or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  Here is the jq incantation assuming you want a "standard" CSV file:

```
jq -Rr 'split("\t") | @csv'
```

In a pinch, the following will probably be sufficient:

```
awk -F"\t" '
BEGIN{OFS=","; QQ="\"";}
  function q(s)   { if (index(s,OFS)) { return QQ s QQ }; return s}
  function qq(s)  { gsub( QQ, QQ QQ, s); return QQ s QQ }
  function wrap(s) { if (index(s,QQ)) { return qq(s) } return q(s)}
  { s=wrap($1); for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {s=s OFS wrap($i)}; print s}'
```

Comment: Editing the files in excel is not an option. If it were, the trim would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS or Linux you can do:

```
cat data.csv | tr -s [:space:] > formatted.csv
```

This will not trim each value but will remove all duplicate spaces. Maybe this will get you going.

Comment: That will remove the excess spaces, but won't trim each value.